# how to trim a string without any spaces

Tags: coldfusion

How do I remove spaces and other whitespace characters from inside a string. I don't want to remove the space just from the ends of the string, but throughout the entire string.

Comment: `trim()` will remove control characters and whitespace so it should deal will most situations. Please post some example data and code.

Comment: I tried trim , but not working...I output each chars in variable with asccivalue..its giving 160(whitespace),32(space) as values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a regular expression

```
<cfset str = reReplace(str, "[[:space:]]", "", "ALL") />
```

Comment: thanks, however i created a function to remove by ascii values with 32,160, it solved the thing

Comment: soorajthomas,what you say you've done to solve your issue only deals with spaces and hard-spaces.  What about tabs, newline/carriage returns etc?  Sean's approach is more thorough.

Comment: why not Trim function?

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply use Coldfusion's Replace() (if you don't want to use regular expressions for some reason - but don't forget the "ALL" optional parameter.

I've run into this in the past, trying to remove 5 spaces in the middle of a string - I would do something like:

```
<cfset str = Replace(str, " ", "")/>
```

Forgetting the "ALL" will only replace the first occurrence so I would end up with 4 spaces, if that makes sense.

Be sure to use:

```
<cfset str = Replace(str, " ", "", "ALL")/>
```

to replace multiple spaces. Hope this helps!