# Remove extra spaces, line feed and carriage return without using regex

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We currently generate an html and then clean up the whitepace (generated even after the CF admin setting)

```
<cfset Str = REReplace(Str, "[#Chr(9)##Chr(10)##Chr(13)#]", "", "all")>
```

It works, but in some of the html is huge and regex shows memory issues. How can I do it without using regex, with simple Replace function may be? Idea is, we can identify beforehand that this html is going to be bigger and parse that through simple Replace instead of regex?

Comment: Isn't there whitespace in the content of the html that needs to be preserved?

Comment: @etchesketch, normal line breaks are implemented with br tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to trim a string without any spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004292/how-to-trim-a-string-without-any-spaces)

Comment: Have you done any tests to see how useful this is? On average, how much white space are you eliminating? How does it really impact performance. To me, this seems like a bandaid approach to a larger issue. The question I would ask is: why is there so much white space that this is actually a problem? Are you not being intentional about what you’re outputting? Or is everything being output, including logic blocks, which do add lots of white space? Still, is it *really* a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've found Lucee's whitespace management to work quite well.  Might be worth a look.

[image]